# Shopify styling isses

Tags: css, shopify, minify

I am using shopify and the template (I believe) is baseline.

In the assets folder there is a theme.css and a theme.min.css. I am finding that the only new styles or over rides I can make are in the min.css file?

There doesnt seem to be a SCSS file. How does theme.css become minified because currently it isn't happening automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes developers add two versions of the stylesheet (.css and min.css), this is just a good practice, but most of the time the minified version (min.css) is connected to theme.liquid. Same happens with .js files.

If you want to add custom styles I recommend to add a new file in the assets folder named "custom.css", for example, and connect it to theme.liquid using the liquid stylesheet tag, something like this:

```
{{ 'custom.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
```

is important to place this tag right under 'theme.min.css' stylesheet tag in the theme.liquid. This way it will override most of the theme.min.css styles.

I don't recommend to use SCSS in Shopify since it is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure I understand what you're using or trying to do, but here's two bits of information that might help:

1. The style being used will be specified in the HTML; so look for tags like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
```

On the page you're working with, you'll see that it probably points to a 'min' version of the css. Change that to change what stylesheet is loaded.

2. If you want to minify your css, there are a bunch of options, including standalone tools, websites, and packages. Here's a good resource for explaining what the process is, and for picking out a way to minify your css:

https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/how-to-minify-your-websites-css-html-javascript

Edit:
Shopify is deprecating Sass, and this article explains what to use instead
https://www.shopify.com/partners/blog/deprecating-sass
"As part of our ongoing initiatives, we've decided to deprecate Sass, with the aim of improving the user experience of storefronts, and paving the way for future advancements. In the short term, Sass will continue to work on Shopify themes, but we are actively migrating our themes to use only CSS stylesheets.

In this article we'll look at why we've decided to transition away from using Sass in themes and how developers can adjust their custom themes to adopt native CSS features and maintain functionality. We'll also look at what alternatives are available for developers who wish to continue using Sass in their development workflow. "

Comment: Yes it is loading the minified version but it seems strange to be editing that. I would have thought you edit theme.css and it would automatically update theme.min.css? I am new to shopify so perhaps it is not that sophisticated ...

Comment: @j00m I just took a look on Shopify, and it looks like they're deprecating this feature:
"The use of Sass on compiled themes is being deprecated, and stylesheets should migrate to native CSS features. For more information on this change and how to use Sass locally in your theme development workflow, please read our announcement blog post on deprecating Sass."
https://www.shopify.com/partners/blog/a-beginners-guide-to-building-shopify-themes-with-sass-part-1-getting-started-with-sass

I've edited the answer with this new info